# Asp Mvc 3 and Synchronization Framework 2.1

Tags: synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework, asp.net-mvc

I am creating application under ASP MVC 3 on x64 platform, and try to work with MS Synchronization Framework 2.1 for synchronize MS SQL Express and MS SQL Compact 3.5 SP2 Databases.
 Client and server should synchronize via WCF services.
 I have examples from Sync SDK with WCF examples.

I want to realize synchronization by click on web page. Actually I creates console application where synchronization by WCF working well. but when I try to do the same logic under ASP MVC 3 in method Synchronize in class SyncOrchestrator return exception:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {EC413D66-6221-4EBB-AC55-4900FB321011} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)). System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {EC413D66-6221-4EBB-AC55-4900FB321011} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)). at Microsoft.Synchronization.KnowledgeSyncOrchestrator.DoOneWaySyncHelper(SyncIdFormatGroup sourceIdFormats, SyncIdFormatGroup destinationIdFormats, KnowledgeSyncProviderConfiguration destinationConfiguration, SyncCallbacks DestinationCallbacks, ISyncProvider sourceProxy, ISyncProvider destinationProxy, ChangeDataAdapter callbackChangeDataAdapter, SyncDataConverter conflictDataConverter, Int32& changesApplied, Int32& changesFailed)

As I know the reason is platform case between x64 and x86. But in all my solution I using the same reference to Sync Framework 2.1. and solution working under console application but not in web.

Is someone know that the my mistake ? may be i need have something special for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using the 32bit install of Sync Framework? if yes, you might want to check the IIS app pool your MVC app is running if the Enable 32-Bit Applications is set to True.

Comment: Thanks JuneT, but I try run in under Visual Studio - ASP.Net Developer server. Is is possible to manage Developer server ? P.S. I upload my App to local IIS but it still has the same issue :(